# How can I read the checked state of a checkbox within the cell of a dynamically created HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JS to determine the checked state of checkboxes which are contained within cells of a table which has been loaded dynamically into a web page.

The page comprises 2 fieldsets:-

```
+-SelectFieldset-----------------------------+
|   <param1>  <param2>   { Load button }     |
|                        {Update button}     |
+--------------------------------------------+
+-ResultFieldset id=resultFS-----------------+
|   Ref_ID   Description     Ready           |
| +-resultTable id=outTable----------------+ |
| |  123     chair            [ ]          | |
| |  167     dresser          [ ]          | |
| |  231     sofa             [ ]          | |
| | ... etc...                             | |
| +----------------------------------------+ |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Notes "[ ]" above depicts a table cell containing an input with type = checkbox;
param1, param2 are dropdown selectors

Initially the ResultFieldset is empty; and is loaded when the "Load" button is clicked (using a JQuery post statement) after the select parameters have been specified.

```
$.post("../listProducts.php", {
 AccName: account,
 From: startDate}, function(data){
  $("#resultFS").after(data);
});
```

Once the resultTable is displayed, the user checks the checkboxes as relevant in the table rows.
Subsequently, when the "Update" button is clicked I need to loop through each table row, read that row's Ref_ID value and then, depending on the checked status of the associated checkbox, post an Update to the specified row of a MySQL table.

The code to loop through the table is:-

```
$("#btnUpdate").on('click', function() {
   for (var i=0, row; row = outTable.rows[i]; i++) {
    var rowRef = row.cells[1].textContent;
    console.log( "Ref_ID = " + rowRef);
    var isChecked = 0;
    if (row.cells[2].firstChild.checked = true){
      isChecked = 1;
      // update MySQL table using rowRef;
    };
     console.log( "Ref_ID = " + rowRef + " Ready = " + isChecked);
   };
};
```

This code logs the Ref_ID values as expected but I'm unable to determine the checkbox state in any row. (The checkboxes are behaving as expected on the webpage - clicking sets & unsets them.)

Please advise on how I should code for this (using either JS or JQuery). Thanks..

Comment: u can add one unique parameter like id to dynamic table cells and then read them by jquery like this $('#cell-' + cell_id)

Comment: `if (row.cells[2].firstChild.checked = true){` <= typo.  `=` (assignment) will make the conditional always true.  Use `==` or `===` correctly

Comment: Taplar, thanks for that - it now works as intended.